# Jira custom script validator: check if input textbox exists

Tags: textbox, jira

I am totally new to Jira. In fact I don't even know where to start.  I went to the jira atlassian website but got nothing solid enough to help me.  I would like to validate if the information entered into a textbox already exists.  I clicked around jira and ended up on the screen below: [image]

Now I would like to find out the following:

> 1. Which programming language should be used for validation ? Is it Java
> 2. If the name of the custom field(of type Textbox) is XYZ and I wanna if check if value entered into XYZ already exist, how do I go about doing that ? Can I just write conditional statements in Java ?

I wrote some stuff and nothing worked.

Comment: those script are written in Groovy. (simplified java but understands regular java too.
What do you exactly mean by checking if a value already exists?

Comment: @Charlie wanna check if the value that is being typed into the textbox already exists(has been captured before) on the jira database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a screenshot from the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview).

There are some documentation and examples for [custom validators](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/recipes/workflow/validators/simple-scripted-validators.html) here.

You can also find an [example here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/recipes/misc/connecting-to-databases.html#_querying_the_current_jira_database) that shows how to query the JIRA (or an external) database from a groovy script. Ie.:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.ConnectionFactory
import org.ofbiz.core.entity.DelegatorInterface

import java.sql.Connection

def delegator = (DelegatorInterface) ComponentAccessor.getComponent(DelegatorInterface)
String helperName = delegator.getGroupHelperName("default");

def sqlStmt = """
    SELECT     project.pname, COUNT(*) AS kount
    FROM       project
               INNER JOIN jiraissue ON project.ID = jiraissue.PROJECT
    GROUP BY project.pname
    ORDER BY kount DESC
"""

Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection(helperName);
Sql sql = new Sql(conn)

try {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer()
    sql.eachRow(sqlStmt) {
        sb << "${it.pname}\t${it.kount}\n"
    }
    log.debug sb.toString()
}
finally {
    sql.close()
}
```

For anything that gets a bit complex it's easier to implement your script in a groovy file and make it available to Script Runner via the file system. That also allows you use a vcs like git to easily push/pull your changes. More info about how to go about that, is [here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/DevEnvironment.html#_a_use_an_existing_instance).

Comment: Hello guys,
Great solution! Just one question: is it safe to use the argument "default" or it depends on some JIRA configuration?

Comment: @VitorPelizza "default" is the delegator-name used in the dbconfig.xml in the JIRA home folder. If you configured other datasources (e.g. in context.xml), then other names than "default" may be available.